# How Can I Get a Python Tkinter Window Open And Close By Itself?

Tags: python, tkinter, window

Basically When The User Clicks On a "Reset" Button It Has To Exit The Current Window And Open It Again So It "Resets". I Hope Someone's Got an Answer Cuz' I Really Need To Finish This Program, and StackOverflow Is a Really Large Programmer Community!

Comment: Have you tried using: `<tkinter.Tk>.destroy()`? If you are going to re-open the window, you can just destroy the widgets that are inside not the whole window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for closing the tab automatically

```
root. destroy()
```

but if you want to close after a particular amount of time please do use the sleep command use this

```
w = tk.Tk()
w.after(30000, lambda: w.destroy()) # Destroy the widget after 30 seconds
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of `lambda: w.destroy()`, just use `w.destroy`. It will run faster and take up less space.

Comment: ohh really thanks mate I learned something new is there any other changes should I do in  code for making it more optimized

Comment: Nope everything else is fine :D.